# Filter record by dates

Tags: sql-server

I want to filter data between two dates but when stored it in temp variable and execute, I get the following error

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 11
>   Error converting data type varchar to datetime

This code works:

```
DECLARE @Where VARCHAR(400)
DECLARE @FromDate DATETIME
DECLARE @ToDate DATETIME

SET @FromDate = '2018-11-02'
SET @ToDate = '2018-11-19' 

SELECT * 
FROM StudentInfo studentinfo 
WHERE CreatedDate BETWEEN  @FromDate AND @ToDate  

CREATE PROCEDURE GetUserData --'2018-11-02','2018-11-17'
    @FromDate DATETIME,
    @ToDate  DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ab VARCHAR(400)
    SET @ab= 'select StudID,FirstName,LastName,CountryCode+(SELECT REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(Contact,''0'','' '')),'' '',''0'')) as Contact,EmailID1,CurrentEdu,PreferredCountry,CurrentInstitution,

CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CreatedDate,103) as RegistrationDate,
OrganisationID,EventId,CreatedDate

  from studentinfo
where 1=1 and
     CreatedDate BETWEEN'+ @FromDate+'and'+ @ToDate+''

     EXEC @ab
END
```

Comment: Can you show us code which doesn't work?

Comment: Why do you use ` CONVERT() ` ? I don't think it is needed here

Comment: I just don't understand.. why would you _not_ post the code that has the issue?

Comment: Although you say your code 'works', you may want to be careful using `between` on datetimes. See the 'Please don't use BETWEEN' section of [Aaron Bertrand's *dating responsibly*](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-dating-responsibly/). If those values are dates, use the `date`  type. If they are `datetime`s, consider renaming the column/variable so it isn't called Date.

Comment: Using dynamic SQL unnecessarily complicates your procedure. In your example you would have to surround the date variables with extra quotes (`'`) to make it work, but it would be much simpler to work with a "plain" `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @ab varchar(400)
  set @ab= 'select StudID,FirstName,LastName,CountryCode+(SELECT REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(Contact,''0'','' '')),'' '',''0'')) as Contact,EmailID1,CurrentEdu,PreferredCountry,CurrentInstitution,

CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CreatedDate,103) as RegistrationDate,
OrganisationID,EventId,CreatedDate

  from studentinfo
where 1=1 and
     CreatedDate BETWEEN BETWEEN '''+convert(varchar, @FromDate , 20)+''' and '''+ convert(varchar,  @ToDate, 20)+''''

     exec (@ab)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

If i guess this code:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CreatedDate,103);
```

this field `CreatedDate` in your table has an invalid value.